# Don't redirect when clicking on a certain child of an anchor element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Right now I have my HTML structured like this:

```
<a class="gallery-item" href="#">
    <div class="top">
        <div class="title"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="bottom">
        <div class="tags">
            <span class="weight"></span><br>
            <span><input type="checkbox" id="read" name="read" value="0"></span>
            <span class="date"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

My problem is currently the checkbox does not change and instead redirects me to the href.

I searched around and found some code that could prerhaps work, however, all of them prevented the checkbox from checking or unchecking.

I tried implimenting this functional myself using jQuery, however this still does not produce results however.

The current code I'm using, item being the parent element in this case.

```
$(item).click(function(e) {
    var sender = $(e.target);

    if (sender.prop("id") == "read") {
       var checked = $("#read", item).prop("checked");

       if (checked == true) {
           $("#read", item).prop("checked", false);
       } else {
           $("#read", item).prop("checked", true);
       }

       return false;
    }

    return true;
});
```

I need a way to trigger the `.change()` of the checkbox as well.

Any help or suggesstions is much appreciated.

Comment: what is item in your code?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `stopPropagation()` method of the event when you click on the `input` to prevent the event bubbling up the DOM and being caught by the event handler on the `a`, something like this:

```
$(item).find('input').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/7t96nkbm/)

Also note that the logic in your click handler is a lot more convoluted than it needs to be, as it's simply toggling the child `input`. Try this:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    $(this).find('input').prop('checked', function(i, p) {
        return !p;
    });
});

$('input').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/7t96nkbm/1/)

You can amend the selectors above to match your specific requirements.

Answer (score 1):

> Right now I have my HTML structured like this: […]

Your problem is that you are creating invalid HTML - and in such cases, you can not expect predictable behavior anyway.

The [content model for the `a` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) is

> Transparent, but there must be no [interactive content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-0) descendant.

An `input` element, if not of type `hidden`, *is* interactive content - and as such not allowed as a descendant of an `a` element.

So the very first thing you should do here, is fix your faulty HTML code.

Comment: I feel as if I was overthinking my situation with this a lot more than it should be, thanks for reminding me I could actually change the element type. However, my true answer came by combinging this and the previous answer together, I just added a ```.click()``` to the item element and and ```stopPropagation()``` on the checkbox still.